# slurm: Is there any way to return unused core number?

Tags: slurm

As we know `squeue` returns the status of the running jobs.

```
squeue
         JOBID PARTITION     NAME     USER ST       TIME  NODES NODELIST(REASON)
           130     debug   run.sh    user PD       0:00      1 (Resources)
           131     debug   run.sh    user PD       0:00      1 (Resources)
           128     debug 52546914    user  R       7:28      1 node1
           129     debug   run.sh    user  R       0:02      1 node1
```

For example my core number is 2.

**[Q]** Is there any way to return only the unused core number? In the example, unused core number should return 0.

Should I write a parser for this in order to retrieve core number next to each `R`, add them, and subtract it from total core number as follows:

```
squeue | grep -P ' R       ' | awk '{print $7}' | paste -sd+ - | bc
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To know the number of **core** (CPUs) that are available in your cluster, you can use the `sinfo` command:

```
$ sinfo -o%C
CPUS(A/I/O/T)
0/1920/0/1920
```

You can retrieve the numbers into Bash variables easily with

```
IFS=/ read A  I O T <<<$(sinfo -h -o%C)
```

After running the above command, `A` will contain the number of allocated cores, `I` will be the number of idle cores, `O` will hold the number of 'other' cores, i.e. drained, down, etc. and `T` will be the total number of cores in the system.

Note that in your question you talk about *cores* but actually compute the number of *nodes*. If what you want is the number of nodes, you can use:

```
$ sinfo -o%A
NODES(A/I)
0/80
```

See the [sinfo man page](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sinfo.html) for more details.

Comment: For example: `nproc --all` returns 8 and ` sinfo -o%C` returns `0/4/0/4`. So should I sum all /* values? but T returns 4 instead of 8 @damienfrancois

Comment: So if I get it correctly, you have only one machine? And you have 4 CPUs on it, probably with hyper threading, which is why `nproc` tells you you have 8 of them. By default, Slurm will ignore hyper threads and consider you have only 4 CPUs

Comment: Yes single machine. `nproc` returns 8. Got it thanks! @damienfrancois

Comment: I am having following warning message: `sinfo: fatal: Options -o(--format) and -l(--long) are mutually exclusive. Please remove one and retry.` is there any alternative way to fetch available cores?

Comment: @alper why do you want both `-o` and `-l`?

Comment: Ah sorry, my bad I was using `sinfo` as an alias for `sinfo -N -l` which was causing the problem.